# Is it necessary to use GC::KeepAlive in C++/CLI when the managed handle is held in a managed container (IList<Foo^>)?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm confused about when I need to use KeepAlive in my C++/CLI wrapper code and how lifetimes are handled in it. Consider the following code and note the places where I ask whether KeepAlive is needed.

```
// convert from managed to native string
inline std::string ToStdString(String^ source)
{
    if (String::IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        return std::string();

    int len = ((source->Length+1) * 2);

    /*** Do I need GC::KeepAlive(source) here? ***/

    char *ch = new char[ len ];
    bool result ;
    {
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars( source );
        result = wcstombs( ch, wch, len ) != -1;
    }
    std::string target = ch;
    delete ch;
    if(!result)
        throw gcnew Exception("error converting System::String to std::string");
    return target;
}

// convert from native to managed string
inline String^ ToSystemString(const std::string& source)
{
    return gcnew String(source.c_str());
}

// unmanaged C++ class
struct NativeDog
{
    std::string name;
    std::string bark() const {return "woof";}
    void eat(std::string& food) const {food.clear();}
};

typedef shared_ptr<NativeDog> NativeDogPtr;

// C++/CLI wrapper class
ref class ManagedDog
{
    NativeDogPtr* base_;
    NativeDog& base() {return **base_;}
    ManagedDog() {base_ = new NativeDogPtr(new NativeDog);}
    ~ManagedDog() {if (base_) delete base_;}
    !ManagedDog() {delete this;}

    property String^ name
    {
        String^ get() {return ToSystemString(base().name);}
        void set(String^ name)
        {
              base().name = ToStdString(name);
              /*** Do I need GC::KeepAlive(name) here? ***/
        }
    }

    String^ bark() {return ToSystemString(base().bark());}
    void eat(String^ food)
    {
         std::string nativeFood = ToStdString(food);
         base().eat(nativeFood);
         food = ToSystemString(nativeFood);
         /*** Do I need GC::KeepAlive(food) here? ***/
    }
};

// unmanaged C++ class
struct NativeKennel
{
    vector<NativeDogPtr> dogs;
};

// C++/CLI wrapper class
ref class ManagedKennel
{
    NativeKennel* base_;
    NativeKennel& base() {return *base_;}
    IList<ManagedDog^>^ dogs;
    void addDog(ManagedDog^ dog)
    {
        base().dogs.push_back(*dog->base_);
        dogs->Add(dog);
        /*** Do I need GC::KeepAlive(dog) here? Will the IList manage the ManagedDog lifetimes? ***/
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right before calling a managed delegate's function pointer.

This is a common failure mode, the garbage collector cannot see any reference held by native code.  The managed code must store a reference to the delegate itself to prevent it from getting garbage collected.  There's a debugger assistant for this, not sure why you didn't see it.  More details in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43yky316%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was holding references to the functors but not the delegates. I hadn't thought about the MDAs. Now with that fixed there's still some issues with the way I'm emulating RAII in the managed classes, but I'll post that separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above!

If you access managed classes in C++/CLI, KeepAlive won't help. You need to pin the data in memory to stop it from relocating afer a garbage collect. In all of these examples, this is done implicitly by the functions you call.

KeepAlive has a different goal. References stored on the stack are subject to garbage collection immediately after the last time the object is dereferenced. KeepAlive prevents this from happening, by extending the lifetime of your object until after the KeepAlive call.

Comment: OK, the problem is in my real code I have NREs which are non-deterministic if I let GC happen non-deterministically and deterministic if I Collect/WaitForPendingFinalizers at a certain point in my code. Right before calling a managed delegate's function pointer.

Comment: is it really just for stack-based references? If so, what is the lifetime for managed-heap references? The function scope?

Comment: @Matt: You're thinking about it wrong.  There's no reference counting, there's no collection when things go "out of scope".  It's all about reachability and memory pressure.

Comment: @Ben: Isn't reachability determined by reference count? I sure would like to think about it correctly...

Comment: @Matt: Reference counting refers to the number of references that haven't themselves been freed.  But .NET uses reachability, which only counts reachable references.  This means that if you have two objects pointing to each other (and no other references to either), in a reference counting scheme, both have 1 reference.  In mark-and-sweep (reachability), both objects are unreachable from the roots (stack variables and static variables are roots) and therefore will be collected.